# Changed cameras, now it's not working

Tags: python, camera

Following tutorials I got a basic first step program working with the Pi Camera Module 3. Then needed to switch cameras to the Arducam x519, and now it terminates itself at the first line.
I followed the instructions and I can open the camera preview from the command prompt, but trying to do it in Python isn't working.

Code

```
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
import time
import numpy as np

print("0")
picam = Picamera2()

print("1")
picam.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
print("2")
config = picam.create_preview_configuration()
print("3")
picam.configure(config)
print("4")

picam.start()
time.sleep(2)
#array = picam.capture_array("main")

#print(array)

picam.close()
```

Error

```
>>> %Run camtest1.py
0
[1:23:34.976388246] [3982]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.1.0+118-563cd78e
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  unordered_map::at

Process ended with exit code -6.
```

I added the print statements to debug, and it's clearly failing at picam = Picamera2(), but searching google I've found nothing matching my problem.